# How to insert to a vector to ensure it remains sorted?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, binary-search

So, I'm storing data in std::vector's, because I need my data to be stored contiguously.  I want to be able to perform binary searches on this data, but I don't want to be calling std::sort all the time, so naturally the place to look is at how data is inserted and deleted into the vector.  How would I go about doing this?

From my understanding the best way to find the proper place to insert is use a binary search.  From what I know of binary searches, though:

```
T binarySearchRecursive(int key, int start, int end)
{
   if (end < start)
      //key does not exist in the vector

   mid = (start + end) / 2;

   if (data[mid] > key)
      return binarySearchRecursive(key, start, mid-1);
   else if (data[mid] < key
      return binarySearchRecursive(key, mid+1, end);
   else // if (data[mid] == key)
      return data[mid];
}
```

What I'm most interested in is the "`if (end < start)`" part, this implies that the entry I'm trying to insert doesn't already exist in the vector.  What I need, however, is a way to return an index or an iterator that would allow me to "`std::vector::insert()`" or "`std::vector::emplace()`" to insert an element at that position.  Between `start`, `end`, and `mid` I should be able to gleam this information, I just don't know how.

Allowing multiple keys to be inserted into vector would simple be a matter of `if (data[mid] == key) data.emplace(mid, args...);`

So, how do I find the correct iterator/index to insert an element into a vector such that it remains sorted?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks, std::lower_bound was exactly what I was looking for.  Why bother writing a binary search that might be buggy, when I can rely on the STL to write a guaranteed correct version for me?